# why cant I see UDP traffic generated by c# application in wireshark?

Tags: c#, wireshark

I am using the UDPClient class to send and receive messages on my loopback address. The executables are also interacting with each other. But why doesnt the traffic appear in wireshark?

BTW I am running windows inside parallels on OSX and can select only 1 interface that is my intel pro net network card in wireshark.

Comment: It may be that loopback traffic doesn't go through the network card, and thus, doesn't show up. You would need to send the traffic elsewhere for it to show up in Wireshark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the key phrase:

> on my loopback address

The loopback address is a complete additional interface, not just an address.  Wireshark is configured to listen on a specific interface, and I'm guessing the loopback interface is not it.

Answer (score 1):

The loopback traffic is not captured by the Net Packet Filter driver.
One workaround is to send it to the IP address of your Intel Pro NIC. In my experience, this is enough to hit the NPF capture driver and show up in Wireshark. (Well, to be accurate, my experience in that matter doesn't involve a VM so YMMV).

Of course, the listener should be bound to that NIC IP to receive the packets (and not only to localhost).